# Increment line number counter in Listing by a value other than one

Tags: listings, code, line-numbering

I'm trying to write some code listings, but the language I am using refers to line numbers that increment by 4. This is similar to how line numbers in BASIC were incremented by 10 per line.

I tried using the option

```
  stepnumber=4
```

but I obviously misinterpreted what this option was intended to do.

It skips the indicated number of lines and only prints line numbers on the intervaled lines. I want every line to have a line number, but have the counter go up by a value other than one(1) each time. Is this possible with the Listings package? Or is there some other solution? I'm relatively new to Tex (i.e. started using it today), so please suggest anything.

Comment: (I think you could use "were" for BASIC increments of 10.  I used them in GWBASIC but QBASIC didn't need explicit line numbering; the editor reports line numbers with consecutive integers).

Comment: The listings source isn't the easiest to follow of the packages I've looked at, but I don't think it's going to be easy unless someone who knows the inner workings can point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can redefine \thelstnumber:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\thelstnumber{\the\numexpr 2*\c@lstnumber\relax}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[numbers=left]
a
b
c
d
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That did the job! Now I just need to dig in and figure out how that renewcommand line works..

Answer (score 3):

You can try

```
\renewcommand*\thelstnumber{\the\numexpr(\value{lstnumber}-1)*4+1\relax}
```

The MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\renewcommand*\thelstnumber{\the\numexpr(\value{lstnumber}-1)*4+1\relax}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[numbers=left]
One
Two
Three
Four
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

then gives

> 1 One
>
> 5 Two
>
> 9 Three
>
> 13 Four

Answer (score 3):

If you just need simple verbatim-style output (no syntax highlighting), this `verbatimbox` approach might work.

EDITED to not automatically reset line number between blocks (using `xpatch`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatimbox,xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\verbnobox}{\setcounter}{\addtocounter}{}{}
\begin{document}
\def\vbmode{\makebox[0pt][r]{\scriptsize\the\numexpr4*\value{VerbboxLineNo}\relax\ }}
\begin{verbnobox}[\vbmode]
This
is
a
test
\end{verbnobox}
More text.
\begin{verbnobox}[\vbmode]
This
is
a
test
\end{verbnobox}
\setcounter{VerbboxLineNo}{0}Reset
\begin{verbnobox}[\vbmode]
This
is
a
test
\end{verbnobox}
\end{document}
```

[image]